# JBoss Development Mode

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x, portlet, liferay-6

I recently started to work on a project in JSF portlets liferay, all running under JBoss AS7

I use liferay 6.1.1 which integrates an embedded  JBoss and therefore I am obliged on each change in my project to deploy all and put in the 'deploy' directory to see what happens! and it is the case even for changes in client side code (xhtml pages, jsf beans ...)

I would like to know if there is a possibility to work with JBoss in development mode which give me the possibility to avoid deploying my application by any changes of interface or client side

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

We use [JRebel](http://zeroturnaround.com/software/jrebel/) for the development of JSF portlets for Liferay on JBoss AS7 and it works pretty good. There is a [wiki page](https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/JRebel) about it on the liferay homepage.